# Modifying routing

Tags: 8, routes

As in Drupal 7, I had this in mymodule_menu() (Implementing hook_menu()):

```
$items['admin/config/mymodule/page1'] = array(
    'title'             => 'Mymodule Page1',
    'page callback'     => 'mymodule_page1',
    'file'              => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
  );
```

So, basically in Drupal 7, whenever I navigated to `/admin/config/mymodule/page1`, it showed me the output of `mymodule_page1` function stored in `mymodule.admin.inc` file.

Modifying this to Drupal 8, I did:

```
`mymodule_menu()`:
  $items['mymodule.page1'] = array(
    'title'              => 'Mymodule Page1',
    'route_name'         => 'mymodule.page1',
  );
```

My `routing.yml` file:

```
mymodule.page1:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule/page1'
  defaults:??
  requirements:??
```

What should be the corresponding code in `defaults` and `requirements` such that the function `mymodule_page1` gets outputted on navigating to that route?

Comment: Routing in Drupal 8 is adopted from symfony2. While this is not going to answer your question but a quick look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html may help.

Comment: @awm: Thanks. I know about this. I just needed to clear my doubt concerning Symfony's implementation in Drupal 8.

Comment: The Drupal 8 routing API handbook is at https://drupal.org/developing/api/8/routing

Answer (score 3):

You can't route to a function, you need to move the content of your function to a controller class and then specify _content: Drupal\yourmodule\Controller\SomeController::someMethod in _defaults, and a _permission: 'some permission' or other access check in requirements.

hook_menu() no longer exists, instead, move your default menu links to a yourmodule.menu_links.yml file.

Almost every core module has plenty examples for this, the necessary documentation has also been linked in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\ContribRoutesOverride.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


/**
 * Class MymoduleRoutesOverride
 */
class MymoduleRoutesOverride implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = 'alterRoutes';
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Alters existing routes.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent $event
   *   The route building event.
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteBuildEvent $event) {
    // Fetch the collection which can be altered.
    $collection = $event->getRouteCollection();
    // Get routes
    $routes = $collection->getIterator();

    foreach ($routes AS $route_name => $route) {
        if ($route_name == 'this_are_the_droids_youre_looking_for') {
          $route->setDefault('_content', '\Drupal\mymodule\Myresponder::page');
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```